# Debugging AWS Lambda node.js ES6

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ecmascript-6, aws-lambda

I am trying to debug an AWS Lambda using lambda-local but the problem is that it doesn't recognize imports and exports in node.js.

Is there a workaround other than back-refactoring my entire API to requires?

Comment: Are you trying to import code on the AWS Lambda side or in your test code? AWS Lambda follows a directory pattern for node modules: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

Answer (score 0):

Imports and exports are not yet supported in Node.

You have two options:
1. Change your imports to use `require`. Or,
2. Use `babel` to transpile your code before deploying to Lambda.

If you use `serverless-framework`, the [`serverless-webpack`](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack) plugin will be of big help to you.